# Getting "Out of Memory" error with small array in loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Somehow I'm getting an "out of memory" error with this array.  It's a sub to get the string from a cell, split it, and use the results to preselect a listbox.  There are only about 10 items in the listbox and I clear the array afterwards.

The sub gets called from inside a loop that searches through rows (i) to see if the text matches that in the userform textbox.  If it does this gets run.

The weird thing is I don't get the error when the sub runs.  I only get it after I unload the userform.

```
Private Sub GetWords (i As Long)
Dim WrdArray() As String
Dim text As String
Dim listnum As Long
Dim wordnum As Long

text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value

WrdArray() = Split(text, ", ")
For wordnum = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)

    For listnum = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If WrdArray(wordnum) = Me.ListBox1.list(listnum) Then
            Me.ListBox1.Selected(listnum) = True
        Else
        End If
    Next

Next
Erase WrdArray()
End Sub
```

Comment: ok, I feel stupid.  This stopped happening when I closed Excel and restarted it.  Not sure what happened.

Comment: If restarting fixed the issue, I suspect that something from your code is hogging the memory, like an array growing in size instead of being reset. Check your global variables imo.